# How to set $PATH variable on Mountain Lion for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, path, osx-mountain-lion

I've got Ruby on Rails installed on my machine. My current $PATH variable looks like this:

```
/Users/smith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/smith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/smith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/smith/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Note that $PATH contains paths to my ruby directories.

While trying to add the path to Postgres.app to $PATH, I created a .bash_profile file in my user's root directory and dropped in:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

After restarting the terminal window, the path to Postgres.app is added just fine but my ruby paths are missing in action.

So what's the proper way to get the path to postgres into $PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Add [export](https://superuser.com/a/18990):

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```